# Why does my for-loop that is supposed to find the product of all values in an array keep telling me each array value instead?

Tags: c++, for-loop, multiplication

Here's what I've got:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    double product = day_changes[0];
    if (x > 0) {
        product *= day_changes[x];
    }
    cout << product << ", ";
}
```

Essentially I already have an array called "day_changes" that has values. I want to multiply all the values in the array together.

I figured that I could have product[0] = day_changes[0], but then I wanted it to go so that product*day_changes[1] = product, and so on for the rest of the array.

Instead, I am just getting the exact numbers I inputted in the first place.

Here's the output:

```
1, 1.0211, 1.00308, 0.99995, 0.999939, 0.995816, 1.00394, 0.999062, 0.998132, 1.00014, 0.995925, 0.9892, 1.0127, 0.995615, 1.00294, 0.992832, 0.999695, 1.02132, 0.996056, 1,
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: That loop is printing "first item in the array" times "current element being explored".

Comment: You're storing your product result *inside* the loop, so it always gets reset to the first element. (Then you multiply it by the current element.) Move it outside: `double product = 1 /* Empty product. */; for (...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the first and last statements outside the for loop. You are reinitializing product and printing it for each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `product` to suitable value outside the loop :-

```
double product = 1.0;                    <<<<< Initialize it. 
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) 
        product *= day_changes[x];
cout << product;                         <<<<< yuppie I got correct value.
```

Comment: Oh geez I feel like a moron. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You **Can Not** access a variable outside the block where it is created. Just declare `double product=1.0` before the loop.